# Get selected item object from ejs-dropdownlist

Tags: typescript, angular8, syncfusion

I'm using `Syncfusion`'s `ejs-dropdownlist` but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I could get the full object in my `FormBuilder` rather than just the `value` from the `[fields]` attribute

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm">
<ejs-dropdownlist [dataSource]="data"
                  [fields]="{text: 'title', value: 'id'}"
                  formControlName="name"
                  placeholder="Select name"></ejs-dropdownlist>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```
 public addForm = this.fb.group({
   name: ['', [Validators.required]]
 });
```

if I log the addForm control I get the id but I'd love to have the full object.

```
console.log(this.addForms.controls.name.value) // '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the selected values object value using getDataByValue public method.

Kindly refer to the below code example.

```html
   <ejs-dropdownlist #dropdown formControlName="skillname" name="skillname" [dataSource]='sportsData' [fields]='fields'
    [placeholder]='autoreactiveplaceholder' floatLabelType='Auto'>
</ejs-dropdownlist>

<button (click)="getObject($event)">ClickTo get the selected value object</button>
```

```
  @ViewChild('dropdown')
  public dropdownObject: DropDownListComponent;

 getObject(args) {
      var fieldObject = this.dropdownObject.getDataByValue(this.skillForm.controls.skillname.value);
      console.log(fieldObject);
    }
```

I have created a sample based on your requirement. please find the sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6i8q3?file=app.component.html

To know more about the public method, please refer the API documentation link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/drop-down-list#getdatabyvalue